# How to remove spaces in printf statement

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, space

I am writing a c program in eclipse to receive data from serial device.

It receive the data properly and store it in receivebuffer. I am using a `printf` statement to print only the `4th,3rd` and `2nd` element of the buffer to console in `hex` format.

Below is the code:

```
printf ("Output is  %02x %02X %02X\n\n", receivebuffer[4], receivebuffer[3], receivebuffer[2]);
```

It is giving following output:

```
Output is 98 0E 88
```

Is there any possible way through which I can remove the spaces between each byte. I want the output in following format:

```
Output is 980E88
```

Is there any function in c to remove space.Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove the spaces between the specifiers:

```
printf ("Output is  %02x%02X%02X\n\n", receivebuffer[4], receivebuffer[3], receivebuffer[2]);
                      //^   ^ No spaces anymore
```

Output:

```
Output is 980E88
```

Comment: one more help..I want the ouput like this: 980.E88 How to do this.??

Comment: @user3668172 I don't think that this is possible in one statement, since you want to split the variable in 2 and put a dot in between

Comment: Is there any way or any sort of code i'll have to add, pls suggest

Comment: @user3668172 Out of my mind I don't think this is possible in a few lines

Comment: can I store values of 3 elements in a variable. So that variable var=980E88 How to do this.

Comment: @user3668172 Yes you can to that! You may want to look into [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

Comment: sscanf is not working or I am doing something wrong. I am not understanding how to deal with sscanf. Can you please help me in code. I have receivebuffer[2]=98 receivebuffer[3]=0E receivebuffer[4]=88 and I want to store all the three values in variable, let's say var so that var=980E88. Please help

Comment: @user3668172 wups linked you the wrong function, here an example how you can do it: http://ideone.com/PZwDlI